# error: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to configure my app using Express like the following way, but I'm getting errors on doing that:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'devleopment';
var app = express();
var config = require('./server/config/config')[env];
require('./server/config/express')(app, config);
app.listen(config.port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + config.port + '...');
```

config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../../');

module.exports = {
  development: {
    db: 'localhost',
    rootPath: rootPath,
    port: process.env.PORT || 3003
  },
  production: {
    rootPath: rootPath,
    db: 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT || 80
  }
}
```

But, noding it on console, I get this error message:

> ```
>     app.set('views', config.rootPath + '/server/views');
>                            ^
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'rootPath' of undefined
>     at module.exports (.\server\config\expr
> ess.js:13:28)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (.\server.js:9:35
> )
>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>     at startup (node.js:119:16)
>     at node.js:906:3
> 23 Jul 10:38:13 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starti
> ng...
> ```

I think that it's comming from the initialization of rootPath. But, I wasn't able to find what's wrong.
How to fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't setting `process.env.NODE_ENV` and it's using the default value, then your problem here is a simple spelling mistake

```
process.env.NODE_ENV || 'devleopment';
```

should be

```
process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
```

Your config file doesn't export an object `devleopment` hence why it returns `undefined`.

Comment: I'm still getting this `throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires callback function');^TypeError: Router.use() requires callback function at Function.use (.\node_modules\express
\lib\router\index.js:416:11)`

Comment: @user3821280 that's a completely different issue, and it's fairly self-explanatory, the `Router.use` method requires a callback you can't just call `Router.use` with no parameters.